# After saving a web page, what does the code in "saved from url" mean?

Tags: google-chrome, html, webpage

Every time I save a web page from Google Chrome, there's something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<!-- saved from url=(0038)http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page --> 
<html lang="en" dir="ltr" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="client-chrome client-chrome-1 client-webkit client-win"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"> 
<title>Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia</title>
```

There's a special comment:

```
<!-- saved from url=(0038)http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page -->
```

What does (0038) mean? In other cases, it can be something different like (0018). What is it?

Comment: What browser is it? when I save e.g. the wikipeida main page in firefox, I don't have that "saved from" special comment. It looks like a feature of your specific browser. You might be able to google your browser name + the numeric codes in parenthesis?

Comment: Please edit the question tags to indicate which browser does this? (The comments seem to indicate Chrome on Windows? Save as, "Web Page, Complete"?)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's an internet explorer security feature called [Mark of the Web](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537628(v=vs.85).aspx). The number is the length of the domain, and it's used to validate the page being loaded for the purposes of running it in the correct 'zone'.